# Есть ли название у приведённого ниже высказывания?

Tags: стилистика

Высказывание следущее: *шум железа пространство-время разрубил*.
Есть ли у высказывания своё название, своя стилистика? Ну, типа, существуют афоризмы, поговорки, пословицы,  слоганы, эпиграммы, басни.  В общем много чего есть. Как такое краткое «изречение» называется? Вроде у Древних Греков в такой форме высказывания были. Читал «Опыты»  М.Монтеня, он в книге на латинском, среди текста, что-то подобное вставлял. Больше, конечно, афоризмы, но всё же и нечто подобное было. Или просто высказывание, и нет у этого названия другого?

Comment: ru.wikipedia.org: Высказывание = предложение, выражающее суждение. Если суждение, составляющее его, предложения, содержание (смысл) истинно, то и о данном высказывании говорят, что оно истинно. Там же: Примером элементарного высказывания может служить 5 < 7. Примером составного логического высказывания может служить если 5 < 7, то 5 — чётное число. ======= Приведённая фраза есть выражение не истинное и элементарное. Вне контекста оно не выглядит законченным, мысль его предваряла или ей только предстоит случиться. Назвать фрагмент можно так, как именуют часть предложения или как приём.

Comment: В каком-то объёме я понял Вас. Не понял про законченность. Точнее вижу законченным. Конечно оно понятней в контексте. В общем, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Если добавить время оно будет законченным?

Comment: Вырванная из контекста фраза всегда не завершённая мысль. Тем более такая: шум время разрубил. Если видите, что она закончена, то, надеюсь, найдётся, кто это поймёт также.

Comment: Метеорит уничтожил динозавров. Это завершённая мысль?

Comment: Может это факт? Хотя, утверждение, которое не может быть непосредственно подтверждено или опровергнуто, называется предположением или мнением.

Comment: Метеорит уничтожил динозавров. ===== Если это произнесено вместо приветствия, т.е. без предварительных вводных о предшествующем мыслительном процессе, то эта фраза потребует завершения. Это будет заметно по лицам присутствующих.

Comment: Я Вас понял. Спасибо за комментарии!

Comment: Нет, всё же, предварительные вводные о предшедствующем могут быть осмыслены самостоятельно. Встретились два учёных давным давно и один другому сразу говорит: метеорит уничтожил динозавров. Говорит с иронией. Второй отвечает: да, это главная тема, я тоже об этом постояно думаю.

Answer (score 2):

Приведенное высказывание можно назвать **изречением, построенным в виде сложной индивидуально-авторской метафоры.**

Для справок

**Изречение** — законченное выражение, преимущественно философского или практически-морального смысла, в пределах минимального интонационного (фраза, период) или метрического (строфа) единства.

**Афори́зм** (от др.-греч. ἀφορισμός «определение») — оригинальная законченная мысль, изречённая и записанная в лаконичной запоминающейся текстовой форме и впоследствии неоднократно воспроизводимая другими людьми.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!